# Combine Table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Here i come up with problem to join Table,so i have a created two column like mon,monthnames from Table `a.KOT_Items` and now i have to combine some more coulmn from tables `Item_Master b,KOT_Main c, Outlet d,Category_Master e,Department_Master f` but no result i am newbie to mysql could some one help on this.

Query::

```
SELECT a.mon,
           a.monthnames,
           d.Outlet_Name,
           e.category_Name,
           f.Department_Name,
           b.Item_Name,
           a.Item_Qty,
           a.Net_amount+a.Item_tax1 AS NetAmount,
           a.Tran_Date
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 AS mon,
              'Jan' AS monthnames
       UNION SELECT 2,
                    'Feb'
       UNION SELECT 3,
                    'Mar'
       UNION SELECT 4,
                    'Apr'
       UNION SELECT 5,
                    'May'
       UNION SELECT 6,
                    'jun'
       UNION SELECT 7,
                    'july'
       UNION SELECT 8,
                    'Aug'
       UNION SELECT 9,
                    'Sep'
       UNION SELECT 10,
                    'Oct'
       UNION SELECT 11,
                    'NoV'
       UNION SELECT 12,
                    'Dec') AS months
    LEFT JOIN a.KOT_Items AS i ON months.mon = MONTH(i.tran_date),
                                               Item_Master b,
                                               KOT_Main c,
                                               Outlet d,
                                               Category_Master e,
                                               Department_Master f

    WHERE
    AND a.Main_Item_Code=b.Item_Code
    AND e.Category_Code=b.Category_Code
    AND e.Category_Code =f.Category_Code
    AND d.Outlet_id = c.outlet_id
    AND a.ref_no=c.ref_no
   GROUP BY a.Bill_No
```

Excepted Result to be

```
mon ||monthname || outlet_name ||  category_Name || Department_Name || Item_Name
```

Update::

```
mon monthnames Outlet_Name      netamount

4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           1
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           100
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS       150
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           1500
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS      
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
1   jan
2   feb
3   mar
5   may
6   june
7   july
8   Aug
9   Sep
10  Oct
11  nov
12  Dec
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT m.mon, m.monthnames, d.Outlet_Name, e.category_Name, f.Department_Name, b.Item_Name, SUM(a.Item_Qty) AS Qty, SUM(a.Net_amount+a.Item_tax1) AS NetAmount
  FROM KOT_Items a,   
       (SELECT 1 AS Mon, 'Jan' AS monthnames
         UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS Mon, 'Feb' AS monthnames
         UNION
        SELECT 3 AS Mon, 'Mar' AS monthnames
         UNION 
        SELECT 4 AS Mon, 'Apr' AS monthnames -- Complete Rest
        ) AS m,
        Item_Master b,
        KOT_Main c,
        Outlet d,
        Category_Master e,
        Department_Master f
  WHERE MONTH(a.tran_date) = m.Mon
    AND a.Main_Item_Code=b.Item_Code
    AND e.Category_Code=b.Category_Code
    AND e.Category_Code =f.Category_Code
    AND d.Outlet_id = c.outlet_id
    AND a.ref_no=c.ref_no
  GROUP BY m.mon, m.monthnames, d.Outlet_Name, e.category_Name, f.Department_Name, b.Item_Name
```

Comment: thanks it works but in my database i had apr month data so it showing but i want to display results for all months in the year, even months that have no transactions in the table

Comment: use Months as starting point and do "LEFT OUTER JOINS" for all other tables. E.g. SELECT .... FROM (SELECT ....) AS m LEFT JOIN KOT_Items a ON MONTH(a.tran_date) = m.Mon .. and so on.

Comment: can you just post the table details (only the columns shown and used in where will do)

Comment: thanks for u r effort now its work fine if i had doubt i will contact u??

Comment: sure, just post it here